# Writeonlyworksheet issue when adding data to file

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Can someone help?

I have this small script with openpyxl that should write to xlsx file but im getting error:

> AttributeError: 'WriteOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'cell'

the error appens in the line mark with ***

```
titulo: checkalllfromdatesbiggerthannumber
xp:  [40.0, 39.0, 42.0, 39.0, 24.0, 22.0, 9.0]
xp1:  [1143.0, 1278.0, 1157.0, 1115.0, 617.0, 484.0, 241.0]
yp:  ['2021-11-08', '2021-11-09', '2021-11-10', '2021-11-11', '2021-11-12', '2021-11-13', '2021-11-14']
```

.

```
    def faz_fich_excell(titulo,xp,xp1,yp):
        print("titulo: ", titulo)
        print('xp: ', xp)
        print('xp1: ', xp1)
        print('yp: ', yp)
        ficheiro = "teste_a.xlsx"

        ayp = list(yp)
        axp = list(xp)
        axp1 = list(xp1)
        titulo = titulo[:30]

        if not os.path.exists(ficheiro):
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
            for x in wb.get_sheet_names():
                std = wb.get_sheet_by_name(x)
                wb.remove_sheet(std)
        else:
            os.chmod(os.path.join(ficheiro), 0o777)
            wb = openpyxl.Workbook(ficheiro)

        wb.create_sheet(titulo.replace(" ", ""))
        ws = wb[titulo.replace(" ", "")]
        ws = wb.active

        r=1
        for y,x,z in zip(ayp,axp,axp1):
            print(y,x,z)
            ws.cell(row=r, column=1).value = str(y)
            ws.cell(row=r, column=2).value = str(x)
            ws.cell(row=r, column=3).value = str(z)

            r += 1

        wb.save(os.path.join(ficheiro))
```

Comment: You can't use `ws["A1"]` access because data has to be written in rows. NB. you shouldn't use this style for your code anyway: as the docs state it is for ad hoc or queries in the shell.

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks, checked that but now got another error, can you check above please.

Comment: `ws.cell` doesn't exist for the same reason: you can't add data randomly in the worksheet only new rows. Just use `ws.append([y, x, z])`

Comment: @CharlieClark thanks, dont have error now, but it doesnt write anything. should i set the row/collumn first?